# How to read the text file and describe it in table using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

---

Here By I tried to read the text file from some source using keyword as SOURCE in MySQL.

And again I want to use the same filename to describe the entire contents of the file to describe it in table format.

Is it possible to do with MySQL?

Commands which I have tried:

```
mysql> use xample;
Database changed
mysql> source /backup/data/perl/awk_output.txt
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SrNoNameSubMarks    
1)AmitPhysics80    
2)RahulMaths90    
3)ShyamBiology87    ' at line 1
mysql> desc awk_output
    -> ;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'xample.awk_output' doesn't exist
mysql>
```

Note:Am not sure is this is the right way to take file from source and describe it in table view using same filename.

```
Please help me with solutions to fix it.


cat awk_output.txt: 

AmitPhysics80    
RahulMaths90    
ShyamBiology87    
KedarEnglish85    
HariHistory89    
HariHistory89
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> use xample;
Database changed
mysql> source /backup/data/perl/awk_output.sql
```

awk_output.sql should be having valid mysql syntax as follows,

```
--> create table tablename;
--> insert into table value (..)
```

then when u do source it will not throw any error.Please check the syntax in awk_output.txt file

Comment: So is it compulsory to have file with .sql extension at source or any extensions can be there. @Prabhakaran Ravichandran

Comment: it can be any extension but the syntax in the file should be in sql format

Comment: I had added my input file(i.e awk_output.txt).This is simple text file.Here what syntax is required. @Prabhakaran Ravichandran